# how does the position work in the getView in the adapter?

Tags: android, android-listview, position

As far as I know, the position returns specific chosen item from the whole list. So how does the adapter use the position and transfers all of the items without some kind of loop? I guess there is a basic mistake in my sight regarding lists and positions.
This is the code:

(THANK YOU IN ADVANCE):

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        viewHolder holder;

if (convertView==null){

    convertView= LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.customupdatestatus, null);
    holder=new viewHolder();
    holder.statusHomePage=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.statusUploaded);
    holder.userNameHomePage=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.userNameUpdate);

    convertView.setTag(holder);
}else{
    holder=(viewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
        ParseObject statusObject= mStatus.get(position);

String username= statusObject.getString("userName");
        holder.userNameHomePage.setText(username);

        String status=statusObject.getString("newStatus");
        holder.statusHomePage.setText(status);

        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is something that was bugging me for some time. So, when the view is created, you can see certain amount of rows. From row one to the last row in the view, adapter is counting. When you scroll down, the counter resets, or, I would say, it starts again. So, lets say you have 10 rows on screen when view is created. When you scroll down, if you select to check row number 5, it will select on the first view, when you scroll, it will show the other element is checked too. I tried to find solution to this, but couldn't.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.but which position is the initial one which is sent to the ListView?before starting the loop

Answer (score 0):

> So how does the adapter use the position and transfers all of the items without some kind of loop?

In short, it doesn't. This is exactly what happens.

The Android framework has separated the process of creating a list into a few different pieces. The ones we care about here are the `ListView` and the `Adapter`.

The `ListView`'s job is to ask the adapter how to map a position to a `View`, then use that information to correctly layout, measure, and draw those `View`s.

The `Adapter`'s job is to tell the `ListView` how to map a position in the list to a `View` instance. Because the Android framework takes care of looping through the items for you in `ListView`, you don't need to worry about doing that yourself- you just need to provide the mapping.

Here is the general idea of what `ListView` does:

```
// Figure out how many children we have
int numChildren = adapter.getCount();

for (int i = 0; i < numChildren; i++) {
    // Get the view for this position
    View childView = adapter.getView(i, null, this);

    // Add it to ourselves
    addView(childView);
}
```

This is of course highly simplified, but is a good high level idea of what is happening with your adapter behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.but which position is the initial one which is sent to the ListView?before starting the loop

Comment: There is no initial position before starting the loop. The first time the `getView()` method is called on your adapter the position will be the first position in the `ListView`. So if you have 20 items, the first `position` passed to `getView()` will be 0.